# JavaScript Cypress : Array keys/values are not printing in console output

Tags: javascript, cypress, javascript-objects, cypress-custom-commands

I'm trying to get the values of nested array object like below,

```
 cy.readFile("excelfile_path", null).then(fulldata => {
            var content = fulldata
            console.log(Object.values(content));
        })
```

**Console Output**
Array[80896]

**Problem**:

1. I'm not able to traverse the nested array objects
2. In Console, its not printing the array keys/values/entries. could only see the total count (`i.e, Array[80896]`)

**Expected**:

1. Search for a string across the FULL array objects and replace with that new string.

*Example:*
var FindString = "**AU5000**"
var ReplaceString = "**THANKYOU01**"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please provide an example of `fulldata`. Currently we have no idea what data you're working with.

Comment: SHORT example of fulldata!

Comment: @Reyno - I'm reading the excel file (which is having multiple worksheets, i,e - Sheet 1, Sheet 2, Sheet 3) and storing all the values t = fulldata

Comment: @mplungjan  - FYR - details updated

Comment: @istaman Not enough details. Please show an example object.